# How to make a transition in CSS while innerHTML is changing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition, innerhtml

I've been having a problem for days: I have a website that changes the content of an element when you click a button. This also works, but I want it to have a transition effect when the content of the element changes.

I've tried giving the element that changes the transition property with CSS, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
  <div class="button-opennav-div">


            

            
            <button onclick="opennav()">
    
                <div id="button-opennav">
    
                    <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                        <path fill="none" d="M1.683,3.39h16.676C18.713,3.39,19,3.103,19,2.749s-0.287-0.642-0.642-0.642H1.683
                            c-0.354,0-0.641,0.287-0.641,0.642S1.328,3.39,1.683,3.39z M1.683,7.879h11.545c0.354,0,0.642-0.287,0.642-0.641
                            s-0.287-0.642-0.642-0.642H1.683c-0.354,0-0.641,0.287-0.641,0.642S1.328,7.879,1.683,7.879z M18.358,11.087H1.683
                            c-0.354,0-0.641,0.286-0.641,0.641s0.287,0.642,0.641,0.642h16.676c0.354,0,0.642-0.287,0.642-0.642S18.713,11.087,18.358,11.087z
                             M11.304,15.576H1.683c-0.354,0-0.641,0.287-0.641,0.642s0.287,0.641,0.641,0.641h9.621c0.354,0,0.642-0.286,0.642-0.641
                            S11.657,15.576,11.304,15.576z"></path>
                    </svg>
    
                </div>
    
          
    
            </button>


        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#div-opennav {

    transition: 1s;

}



.nav2 a {

    text-decoration: none;

    color: white;



    padding: 1rem;

    transition: 1s;


}









.nav2 a:hover {

background-color: rgb(71, 205, 194);
transition: 0.5s;





}


.nav2 {

    display: inline !important;

    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;

    transition: 1s;
 

}
```

JavaScript:

```
function opennav() {


document.getElementById('changed-element').innerHTML = `

<div class="button-opennav-div" id="changed-element">


<div class="nav2" id="nav2">

    <a href="">Link</a> 
    <a href="">Link</a>
    <a href="">Link</a>
    <a href="">Link</a>
</div>


<button onclick="closenav()">

<div id="button-opennav">

    <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <path fill="none" d="M1.683,3.39h16.676C18.713,3.39,19,3.103,19,2.749s-0.287-0.642-0.642-0.642H1.683
            c-0.354,0-0.641,0.287-0.641,0.642S1.328,3.39,1.683,3.39z M1.683,7.879h11.545c0.354,0,0.642-0.287,0.642-0.641
            s-0.287-0.642-0.642-0.642H1.683c-0.354,0-0.641,0.287-0.641,0.642S1.328,7.879,1.683,7.879z M18.358,11.087H1.683
            c-0.354,0-0.641,0.286-0.641,0.641s0.287,0.642,0.641,0.642h16.676c0.354,0,0.642-0.287,0.642-0.642S18.713,11.087,18.358,11.087z
             M11.304,15.576H1.683c-0.354,0-0.641,0.287-0.641,0.642s0.287,0.641,0.641,0.641h9.621c0.354,0,0.642-0.286,0.642-0.641
            S11.657,15.576,11.304,15.576z"></path>
    </svg>

</div>



</button>


</div>

`;









}



function closenav() {

    document.getElementById('changed-element').innerHTML = `

    <div class="button-opennav-div" id="changed-element">
    
    

    
    
    <button onclick="closenav()">
    
    <div id="button-opennav">
    
        <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
            <path fill="none" d="M1.683,3.39h16.676C18.713,3.39,19,3.103,19,2.749s-0.287-0.642-0.642-0.642H1.683
                c-0.354,0-0.641,0.287-0.641,0.642S1.328,3.39,1.683,3.39z M1.683,7.879h11.545c0.354,0,0.642-0.287,0.642-0.641
                s-0.287-0.642-0.642-0.642H1.683c-0.354,0-0.641,0.287-0.641,0.642S1.328,7.879,1.683,7.879z M18.358,11.087H1.683
                c-0.354,0-0.641,0.286-0.641,0.641s0.287,0.642,0.641,0.642h16.676c0.354,0,0.642-0.287,0.642-0.642S18.713,11.087,18.358,11.087z
                 M11.304,15.576H1.683c-0.354,0-0.641,0.287-0.641,0.642s0.287,0.641,0.641,0.641h9.621c0.354,0,0.642-0.286,0.642-0.641
                S11.657,15.576,11.304,15.576z"></path>
        </svg>
    
    </div>
    
    
    
    </button>
    
    
    </div>
    
    `;

}
```

Comment: Looks like a simple nav open/close function: so why not leave the nav list static and just toggle its appearance on click (e.g opacity and height)? See [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/BavQvBN)